# Installing mailparse php7 mbstring error

Tags: php-extension, php-7, email-parsing

I'm currently working to put our project under php7.

When trying to compile the mailparse extension or use pecl to install it, I get this error:

`#error The mailparse extension requires the mbstring extension!`

I did install the php7.0-mbstring and tried to put the mbstring extension with the mailparse source code. I also tried to use my old C skills and try include the libraries myself without success.

Any of you has an idea how I could solve my problem? (without editing the code like I saw in some forums)

Thanks

Comment: Confirm both `mailparse` and `mbstring` extensions enabled by examining the output of `phpinfo()`

Comment: After looking, I can confirm that mbstring is installed and enabled. But since mailparse doesn't get installed cause of the error, it is missing

Answer (score 39):

You should be able to download the mailparse source, comment out the test for `HAVE_MBSTRING` in `mailparse.c` (around line 34), and build it normally.

Here's what I did in Ubuntu 16.04 (assume 'sudo' when necessary):

```
cd /tmp

apt-get install php7.0-dev

pecl download mailparse

tar xvzf mailparse-3.0.2.tgz

cd mailparse-3.0.2

phpize

./configure

sed -i \
  's/^\(#error .* the mbstring extension!\)/\/\/\1/' \
  mailparse.c

make

make install
```

Then you just need to enable the `mailparse.so` module in your PHP configuration.

For Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP-FPM, you'd use:

```
echo "extension=mailparse.so" > \
  /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/30-mailparse.ini

service php7.0-fpm reload
```

Comment: I saw your note about "without editing code".  I should mention that Zend's own help resources recommend the same fix: https://support.zend.com/hc/en-us/articles/203408233-Compile-mailparse-extension-with-mbstring-dependency-

Comment: I just wanted to add that phpize will not work unless you have installed php7.0-dev (e.g. sudo apt install php7.0-dev)

Comment: Good call, @KevinRemisoski.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are in Ubuntu 16 LTS Its best to create symbolic link


`echo "extension=mailparse.so" > \
  /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mailparse.ini`


`ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mailparse.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/30-mailparse.ini`


`ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mailparse.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/30-mailparse.ini`