# PHP7 Extension won't install

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, php-7

I'm trying to install the mailparse extension, either via

```
phpize
make
make install
```

but also via

```
pecl install mailparse
```

but i keep getting the error that it requires `mbstring`, which is installed and enabled.

I get this error:

```
 #error The mailparse extension requires the mbstring extension!
  ^
Makefile:200: recipe for target 'mailparse.lo' failed
make: *** [mailparse.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

`php -i | grep mbstring`:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
mbstring
mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.
mbstring.detect_order => no value => no value
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.func_overload => 0 => 0
mbstring.http_input => no value => no value
mbstring.http_output => no value => no value
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
mbstring.language => neutral => neutral
mbstring.strict_detection => Off => Off
mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value
```

PHP Version:

PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Any ideas on how to install ?

Comment: Found a resolution to the issue via another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793216/installing-mailparse-php7-mbstring-error/36636332

Comment: I'm marking this a duplicate since you found the answer on the other thread.