# Install mailparse PHP extension on laravel forge + digital ocean

Tags: php, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

I am have provisioned a server on digital ocean (Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64) and I use laravel forge to manage it.  I have a laravel app Im trying to install but it requires the PHP mailparse extension.  [Reading this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793216/installing-mailparse-php7-mbstring-error) I am trying to install a the PHP mailparser extension but each time I do and try to proceed with installing my app I get this error in console:

```
    Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser 2.8.0 -> satisfiable by php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser[2.8.0].
    - php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser 2.8.0 requires ext-mailparse * -> the requested PHP extension mailparse is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I verified using `phpinfo()` that everything else is enabled.  I just cant seem to get the `the requested PHP extension mailparse is missing from your system` error to go away so I can proceed with installation.

I am a bit out of my depth here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

** ***UPDATE*** **

Here is what happens when I run php --ini from terminal

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini
```

Comment: Where are you running `phpinfo();` pretty common for cli and apache2 to have their own php.ini. I understand composer will use `cli/php.ini` so make sure that is the one you are checking. `also run php --ini inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI`

Comment: Just updated question to show what my terminal says when I run that command

Comment: @JasonJoslin I was adding a comment to your answer but to give you perspective on what I tried I created a paste of my terminal output.  If I were to guess it is because it is installing the module in the /tmp folder and not where the others are?  https://pastebin.com/BUe56JH1